# Spring Service doesnt return list of users

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "users")
    public class User {

    private int userId;

    private String firstName;

    private String middleName;

    private String lastName;

    private String login;

    private String password;

    @Transient
    private String confirmPassword;

    private int sex;

    private String email;

    private Set<Role> roles;

    public User(){}

    public String getConfirmPassword() {
        return confirmPassword;
    }

    public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
        this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
    }

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")})
    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Column(name = "middle_name")
    public String getMiddleName() {
        return middleName;
    }

    public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
        this.middleName = middleName;
    }

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Column(name = "login")
    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    @Column(name = "password")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Column(name = "sex")
    public int getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public void setSex(int sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    @Column(name = "email")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "userId=" + userId +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", middleName='" + middleName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", login='" + login + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", sex=" + sex +
                ", email=" + email +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof User)) return false;

        User user = (User) o;

        if (userId != user.userId) return false;
        if (sex != user.sex) return false;
        if (!firstName.equals(user.firstName)) return false;
        if (middleName != null ? !middleName.equals(user.middleName) :   user.middleName != null) return false;
        if (!lastName.equals(user.lastName)) return false;
        if (login != null ? !login.equals(user.login) : user.login != null) return false;
        if (password != null ? !password.equals(user.password) : user.password != null) return false;
        if (confirmPassword != null ? !confirmPassword.equals(user.confirmPassword) : user.confirmPassword != null)
            return false;
        if (!email.equals(user.email)) return false;
        return roles != null ? roles.equals(user.roles) : user.roles == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = userId;
        result = 31 * result + firstName.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + (middleName != null ? middleName.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + lastName.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + (login != null ? login.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (password != null ? password.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (confirmPassword != null ? confirmPassword.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + sex;
        result = 31 * result + email.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + (roles != null ? roles.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}

    @Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDaoImpl.class);

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public void addUser(User user) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.persist(user);
        log.info("User saves successfully. User details: " + user);
    }

    public void updateUser(User user) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.update(user);
        log.info("User updated successfully. User details: " + user);
    }

    public void removeUser(int id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        User user = (User) session.load(User.class, id);
        if(user != null) {
            session.delete(user);
        }
        log.info("User removed successfully. User details: " + user);
    }

    public User getUserById(int id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        User user = (User) session.load(User.class, id);
        log.info("User loaded successfully. User details: " + user);
        return user;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<User> listUsers() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<User> userList = session.createQuery("from users").list();

        for (User user : userList) {
            log.info("User list: " + user);
        }

        return userList;
    }
}

    @Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    private UserDao userDao;

    public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void addUser(User user) {
        userDao.addUser(user);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        userDao.updateUser(user);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void removeUser(int id) {
        userDao.removeUser(id);
    }

    @Transactional
    public User getUserById(int id) {
        return userDao.getUserById(id);
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<User> listUsers() {
        return userDao.listUsers();
    }
}

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

  <display-name>Notes Web Application</display-name>
    <!--Zkoss config-->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.HttpSessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <description>The ZK loader for ZUML pages</description>
        <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>update-uri</param-name>
            <param-value>/zkau</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.zul</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.zhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <description>The asynchronous update engine for ZK</description>
        <servlet-name>auEngine</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>auEngine</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/zkau/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <!--Spring config-->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/pages/index.zul</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.mightynoobs.springhibernate"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.mightynoobs.springsecurity"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <!--Database information-->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url"
                  value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mightynoobsdb"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="admin"/>
    </bean>

    <!--Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition-->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>ru.mightynoobs.springhibernate.model.user.User</value>
                <value>ru.mightynoobs.springhibernate.model.user.Role</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--UserDao and UserService beans-->
    <bean id="userDao" class="ru.mightynoobs.springhibernate.dao.user.UserDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="userService" class="ru.mightynoobs.springhibernate.service.user.UserServiceImpl">
        <property name="userDao" ref="userDao"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!--Zkoss controller's-->
</beans>


    <window id="window" title="User List" border="normal"
        apply="ru.mightynoobs.springhibernate.controller.UserNotesListController">
    <listbox id="listbox" model="${window$composer.userModel}" checkmark="true" mold="paging" pageSize="9">
        <listhead>
            <listheader width="32px" />
            <listheader label="First Name" align="center" sort="auto(firstName)" />
            <listheader label="Middle Name" align="center" sort="auto(middleName)" />
            <listheader label="Last Name" align="center" sort="auto(lastName)" />
            <listheader label="Sex" align="center" sort="auto(sex)"/>
            <listheader label="eMail" align="center" sort="auto(email)" />
        </listhead>
        <template name="model">
            <listitem>
                <listcell/>
                <listcell label="${each.firstName}"/>
                <listcell label="${each.middleName}"/>
                <listcell label="${each.lastName}"/>
                <listcell label="${each.sex}" style="text-align: right"/>
                <listcell label="${each.email}" style="text-align: right"/>
            </listitem>
        </template>
    </listbox>
</window>

and after running tomcat i have this





    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [zkLoader] in context with path [] threw exception
     java.lang.NullPointerException
        at ru.mightynoobs.springhibernate.service.user.UserServiceImpl.listUsers(UserServiceImpl.java:45)
        at ru.mightynoobs.springhibernate.controller.UserNotesListController.<init>(UserNotesListController.java:32)
```

Sorry for this view of code. Need help with this null pointer. So i have NullPointer. My DB is not empty. Users table has 1 row. It's first time i try integrate zkoss with Spring. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should use class name in HQL instead of table name.

Comment: do u mean change this session.createQuery("from users").list() to 
session.createQuery("from User").list() ?

Comment: `session.createQuery("from User").list() ` is correct. Or the query can be `select U from User U`